how to implement thread-pool continuation?
I have a rather simple threadpool implementation for which I need to write a continuation. When a task is enqueued in threadpool it returns an std::future. A caller can then want to enqueue tasks that depend on those futures. So I need a function that takes self-contained task, a list of futures and  return a future of that asynchronous operation. Here is a demonstration:
threadpool tp;

// enqueue two tasks in threadpool and get back the futures
auto f1 = tp([](auto v) { return do_something(v); 1});
auto f2 = tp([](auto v) { return do_something(v); 2});

// desirable non-starving threadpool::then
auto f3 = tp.then([](auto v1, auto v2) 
{ 
    return do_something(v1 + v2); 
}, std::move(f1), std::move(f2));

// naive starving implementation
auto naive = tp([](auto&& f1, auto&& f2)
{
    return do_something(f1.get(), f2.get());
}, std::move(f1), std::move(f2)));

The obvious problem that arises with this naive implementation is that threadpool would be starved if it contains blocked threads waiting on futures to get ready. A simple solution would be creating a thread outside of the threadpool waiting on futures, which is also a bad solution as it's impossible to know how many such suspended threads would be created and it's a slow solution as well.
What would be an optimal way of creating threadpool continuations without creating stray threads or starving the threadpool?

If you want to do this all yourself, one approach is to wrap your task & std::future in your own types that track dependent tasks, with a refcount. Only when the last dependency completes, would it add your "then" task to the queue at all.

@Useless -- how are you suggesting using a single refcount? There can be arbitrary number of tasks depending on arbitrary number of futures. You would need a refcount for every task and future combination.

Each task has a number of prerequisite futures. That's the refcount. It reaches zero when all the prerequisites are satisfied, and then the dependent task can be enqueued without blocking. Do note these need to be shared_futures though if you're allowing multiple tasks to depend on the same future.

@Useless -- how is dependent's refcount going to be decremented? Dependent cannot be waiting, there is no place for it to wait. So dependent must be run in a callback. Multiple, call it smart futures, would have multiple dependents, which means every smart future must keep an arbitrary long list (vector) of dependents and try to call each one back when it becomes ready. I guess your suggestion is to have an atomic refcount in every dependent, so the last future that becomes ready executes callback in its thread. I think it going to be quite heavy (slow) implementation.

Slow, but compared to what? This is the canonical approach and large parts of the world's software run exactly like this.

You need to track dependencies somewhere. If you allow each task to have an arbitrary list of dependent tasks, you're going to have a variable-length container somewhere. If you don't want that, you have to weaken the requirements by having a capped number of dependencies per task, or something similar. Honestly you could implement this with std::shared_ptr and a custom deleter and have something to benchmark in no time.

@Shaggi -- this algorithm adds a burden even for tasks that don't have dependencies.

If "look at container, is it empty, then do nothing" is a heavy burden, it may be that your tasks are too small

The obvious alternative is to have a statically-composed dependency graph, but you can't build that on-the-fly in the way you show without a load of lazily-evaluated expression template metaprogramming.

@Useless -- that actually sounds reasonable, delaying the execution until compiler built all dependencies, and then run threadpool until it's drained and destroy it. Not sure all my use cases allow this. The example is still fine, just need to make sure no tasks are added after threadpool started running.

It turns out that combining the "create task" with "queue task for running" causes a problem in C++.  This is why there is an executors proposal.
So the first thing you should consider is changing how you set up tasks for the thread pool.
A simple replacement for the idea of a std-future returning task is a pipeline element.
template<class In, class Out>
struct PipelineElement;

template<class... In, class...Out>
struct PipelineElement<void(In...), void(Out...)> {
  std::function<In..., std::function<void(Out...)>> operation;

  PipelineElement(std::function<In..., std::function<void(Out...)>> f):
    operation(std::move(f))
  {}
  PipelineElement(PipelineElement const&)=default;
  PipelineElement(PipelineElement &&)=default;
  PipelineElement& operator=(PipelineElement const&)=default;
  PipelineElement& operator=(PipelineElement &&)=default;

  template<class...Result>
  PipelineElement<void(In...), void(Result...)>
  operator|(
    PipelineElement self,
    PipelineElement<void(Out...), void(Result...)> next
  ) {
    return [self=std::move(self), next=std::move(next)]( In... in, std::function<void(Result...)> continuation ) mutable {
      self.operation( std::forward<In>(in)...,
        [next=std::move(next), continuation=std::move(continuation)]
        ( Out... out ) mutable {
          next.operation( std::forward<Out>(out)..., std::move(continuation) );
        }
      );
    };
  }
 
};

template<class...In>
using Sink = PipelineElement<void(In...), void()>;
template<class...Out>
using Source = PipelineElement<void(), void(Out...)>;

template<class F, class R=std::invoke_result_t<F>>
Source<R> MakeSource( F&& f ) {
  return [f=std::forward<F>(f)]( auto sink ) mutable {
    return sink(f());
  };
}
template<class...In>
Sink<In...> MakeSink( std::function<void(In...)> f ) {
  return [f=std::move(f)]( In... in, auto Done ) {
    f(std::forward<In>(in)...);
    Done();
  };
}
template<class...In, class R>
PipelineElement<void(In...), void(R)> MakePipeline( std::function<R(In...)> f ) {
  return [f=std::move(f)]( In... in, auto Done ) {
    Done(f(std::forward<In>(in)...));
  };
}
template<class...In>
PipelineElement<void(In...), void()> MakePipeline( std::function<void(In...)> f ) {
  return MakeSink( std::move(f) );
}

these things can be composed at will.
The callbacks can be scheduled, or run in sequence.
So instead of putting a task on a thread pool, you build the task get a PipelineElement out of it, you attach the next steps to it, then you give the PipelineElement to the thread pool.
Making the last step activate a std::future is easy.

If you are married to it being a set up the task to run then plan what happens next, you have to add some (needless) concurrency work, as the task may be finished before you plan the next step.
This can still use these pipeline elements.  A thread pool could return a pipeline element: a Source<int> can replace your std::future<int>.
A Source<int> is merely a callable that accepts a std::function<void(int)> - converting that into a std::future<int> is easy:
template<class R>
std::future<R> FutureFromSource( Source<int> src ) {
  auto pp = std::make_shared<std::promise<R>>();
  src.operation( [pp](R r){ pp->set_value(std::forward<R>(r)); } );
  return pp->get_future();
}

A side effect of this Source/Sink/Pipeline is that you don't generally write code that waits on stuff.  Instead, your components schedule code to run somewhere.
If you want code to run on the main or UI thread, you need a main or UI thread scheduler.  If you want it threaded off, you need a thread pool.  Etc.
Code stating "I want to stop running until this code is finished" can't be written, which is good because in async code you shouldn't write that code.
...
The other alternative is to replace your std::futures with your own toys.  These have both storage for a T and a std::function<void(T)> and a mutex and an executor:
template<class T>
struct nexter {
  struct state {
    mutable std::mutex m;
    std::optional<T> value;
    std::function<void(T)> sink;
    std::function<void(std::function<void()>)> executor;
    mutable std::condition_variable cv;
  };
  std::shared_ptr<state> pstate;
};

you can implement .wait and .then on top of this.
.then takes a void(T) and appends it to sink; if the value is ready, it passed the value and the sink to executor (which can include "run immediately").
Making it ready populates the optional.  If the sink exists, it runs it on the executor.  It also signals the condition variable.
It is a bit of beast really.
Appending to the sink consists of assigning if the sink is empty.  Otherwise, you write a function that calls the first sink, then the second.
Decisions about "do you support multiple .then?" and the like have to be made.

Excellent information, thought I can't break backward compatibility for existing thread pool, I can design an alternative one. Building pipeline at compile time looks attractive.

@Gene You can expose the thread pool/future API on top of a pipeline based one with very little overhead; a pipeline element that fullfills a promise when completed is basically what your thread pool is doing.  Then people who want robust .then() chaining can use the pipeline API, where they set up their pipes (including an eventual notification is it complete) and kick them off once the system is set up.

Have your task queue only contain entries that are ready to be executed.
When enqueuing with dependencies from prior scheduled tasks, add the new task as dependency to each existing one.
The threadpool dequeues only tasks from the "ready to go" list, and whenever a task is finished, decrement a counter on every dependent. If the counter reaches 0 (no more dependencies), you can either execute the child directly or push it into the task list again.
Such a system will never starve, but it requires avoiding user code awaiting the dependencies directly (through futures in your example) and instead formalize it through the scheduling API instead.

Note that above doesn't "nicely" package dependency and data safely together. Perhaps there is a magic template solution that takes the futures as arguments, and accepts a callable that takes the inner results from the futures?

It would be nice to see the code. If there is a polling of dependencies (futures) to determine if they are ready then it would be a very inefficient implementation. It's easy to enqueue a task which would be checked if it's ready on every dequeue, and enqueued back if it's not ready, but that implementation is too slow to be practical.

Here's an example:
https://bitbucket.org/Mayae/cpl/src/fa8e21e191501078c7db5e9cc14e430af9c16bb3/JobSystem.h?at=dev%2Fstable#lines-148
You use a condition_variable that the pool awaits on, so the OS efficiently wakes up thread when there's work available.
